# Temporary failure in name resolution in ssh command

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, display-resolution, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I haven't used my Ubuntu WSL in about 4 months, today I opened it up to use ssh to connect to a server for one of my classes and I get the following error. I've tried the other solutions that I've found here on stack exchange etc with no success. As well I need a permanent solution as this is going to be used on a daily basis. I don't quite understand what happened for it to now suddenly not work and would appreciate some sort of answer to this. I also cannot run 'sudo apt update' either.

[image: Screenshot of WSL]

Comment: Please do not submit pictures or screenshots of your terminal.  Instead copy/paste commands with the corresponding terminal output and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to preserve line breaks and monospace formatting.

Comment: You should edit your question with the details you left out.  You should include the details of your research, what you've tried, and the results of those attempts showing how/why it did not work for you. Include also the output of `sudo apt update`